# Making soda with yeast

Tags: yeast, drinks, soda

It is easy to make soda by adding sugar and yeast to a bottle of water and closing it tightly. However, checking different recipes, I did not get what is the best condition for this. I have a couple of tiny questions to find the optimum treatment.

I added 1/2 tsp instant yeast (baking yeast) and 1 tsp sugar to 2 l of water.

1. Should the bottle left untouched, or it is useful to shake it
   occasionally?
2. To keep it warm, is it good to put it in sunshine, or
       a dark place is better for it?
3. Leaving air in the bottle or filling it completely?

Comment: I would be surprised if you could make anything that tastes decent this way, without any flavorings. Also, the absence of nutrients for the yeast might be a problem if you're just using sugar and water.

Comment: @user5561 I agree with you, the taste i not decent in my experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with @SAJ14SAJ. What I would add is that

- yeast does not require sunlight in any way ... but as UV light can be harmful to microorganisms and [might inhibit yeast growth](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=effect%20of%20UV%20on%20yeast%20growth&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=LHL2UZSVEcOKOKbYgYgE&ved=0CCkQgQMwAA) I wouldn't brew it in direct sun.
- for bottling beer it is normally suggested to leave the correct amount (1 - 1 ½ inch) of headspace (air) at the top of the bottle for carbonation and proper pressure. But I am not sure if the same conditions apply for soda - I would think it is not too different.
- shaking gently occasionally might help to evenly distribute the yeast in the sugar solution, and expose it to more food resources (sugar).

Answer (score 3):

There are many resources on the web for [home brewing soda](https://www.google.com/search?q=brewing%20home%20made%20soda), which you may wish to google.

Of your specific questions, the only one I was able to find a clear answer to is that the fermentation temperature should be on the order of 70-80 F / 21 - 27 C, per [Home Brewing.Org](http://www.homebrewing.org/How-to-Make-Soda_ep_44-1.html).

There is no mention in any of the articles I have seen of turning or shaking the bottles.  Similarly, none of the ones I surveyed mentioned fill depth; common sense would indicate filling to within an inch or so (2 cm) of the shoulder of the bottle, as is typical.

For safety, *do not do this with glass bottles*.  There is a risk of explosion, broken glass, and of course, sticky mess.

Note:  The Stack Exchange Home Brewing site has a [Soda](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/search?q=soda) tag.  They may be a better fit for questions like this.

Comment: Actually, I explored several recipes, but no mention to the points I raised. Since this is a long process (a few days), I am curious about the right way to conduct the process, because it can have a significant effect on dissolving of the CO2 produced in water.. And thanks for the safety issues, it is of utmost importance. I am using a plastic bottle.

Comment: I suggest asking over at the Home Brewing site.  They may have better insight.

Comment: Note that in terms of dissolving CO2 in water, the relevant factors are pressure and temperature (and to a lesser extent, time).   Shaking would not effect this very much. Contrary to experience dissolving solids in water, most gasses including CO2 actually dissolve in water better as the temperature *decreases*.